# Problem in the function "niche.overlap" of the Phyloclim R Package

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the `niche.overlap` function by inputting a pno object obtained in the `phyloclim` package:

```
library(phyloclim)
x <- pno(path_bioclim = "C:\\Users\\test phyloclim 2\\Nova pasta (3)\\bio2.asc",
         path_model = "C:\\Users\\Nova pasta (4)",
         subset = NULL , bin_width = 1, bin_number = 100)

niche.overlap(x)
```

I expect to get a matrix but instead I get got the following error:

> Error in niche.overlap(x) : object 'DI' not found

Answer (score 0):

One must only export the object as a .csv file, and then import again as a table. It should work fine.